# Aspnet core proxy request when webapp doesn't match the route

Tags: asp.net-core

so, i have a WebAPI that handles some routes, and needs to pass the rest to a downwards REST API like this

frontend ---> MyWebAPI --> AnotherAPI

any request that returns a 404(or not, i'm happy with everything that doesn't match an existing route)

i managed to do a proxy using MapWhen and aspnetcore.Proxy middleware. but that executes before any route matching, so i can't know if the request will match or not.

```
app.MapWhen((context) =>
                    context.Response.StatusCode == 404,
                    builder =>
                    builder.RunProxy(new ProxyOptions
                    {
                        Scheme = "http",
                        Host = Configuration.GetValue<string>("APIAddress"),
                        Port = Configuration.GetValue<string>("APIPort")
                    }));
```

is there a way to execute this after the route matching? 
another way would be to have a catch all route like this:

```
[Route("{*url}", Order = 999)]
public IActionResult CatchAll()
{
    //do the proxying here
}
```

but then i would have to manage all nuances of correctly proxying a request by hand.